# Verifying that a string contains only letters in C++

Tags: c++, string, validation

I only found information about this topic using C#, and i'm using C++.
Hope you can help me with this.

**My code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  // Librería para el manejo de archivos
#include <string>   // Librería para el manejo de strings
#include <stdlib.h> // Librería para el uso de system("cls");

int main()
{
    //Variables
    string NombreJugador;

/*  Content
------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    do
    {
        cout << "Your name: ";
        cin >> NombreJugador;
    } while(ValidarNombreJugador(NombreJugador));

    return 0;
}

/*  Function
------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int ValidarNombreJugador(string NombreJugador)
{
    int Numero;

    Numero = atoi(NombreJugador.c_str());

    if (Numero!=0)
    {
        cout << "No puede ingresar numeros, solo letras." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Perfecto, tu nombre no tiene numeros." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I have found on Google this way to validate that the name only have letters and not numbers.

The problem is that if you enter "0", it recognize it as a letter, a mean, it returns true.

**What should I do to properly validate that the string has only letters and not numbers?.**

I'm new using string by the way.

Comment: you also tested only that your input not start with numbers, if it contains numbers in the middle or at the end it pass your test.

Comment: "Only letters" and "no numbers" are different things. Which one do you actually want to test for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No numbers:

```
if(std::none_of(str.begin(), str.end(), [](unsigned char c){return std::isdigit(c);})) {
    // stuff
}
```

All letters:

```
if(std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), [](unsigned char c){return std::isalpha(c);})) {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Hi men, thanks but, let me ask you something, your code is in C++?... is a little confusing to me.

Comment: @RobertGomez Yes, this code is C++.